# Is there any granularity over what folks can access in Site Settings?

Tags: site-collection, site

SharePoint 2010. I'd like to know if anybody knows a way to restrict what a superuser has access to with a given site or site collection's Site Settings area? I'd like to open up some resources in there, but not the whole kit 'n kaboodle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5 different permission levels that you get out of the box (Full Control, Design, Contribute, etc) are created from 33 different fine grained permissions.

You can create a new permission level from those fine grained permissions somewhere between "Design" and "Full Control", e.g. to allow a user to create subsites but not manage permissions. Permission levels and permissions are documented here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx

I don't think you can go finer than those 33, at least not out of the box, so if you want part of what's granted by Manage Web Sites, but not all, you may be out of luck.